# How to access python file in other directories?

Tags: python, directory, python-import

This is my file structure in vscode:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQTEo.png)

I have some general functions in my "general.py" file. For some reason if I try to

```
import general
```

inside any of the files located in "telefone" folder it works fine but, I can't import like this on "rotinas" folder files, inside that folder I need to

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('settings'))
import general
```

why is it happening?

I tried creating "`__init__.py`" files inside my folders, no success.

Comment: try to name the file w8 __ init __ .py instead of init.py. Note: remove the spaces.

Comment: here also a good tutorial for you https://www.webucator.com/article/how-to-create-a-python-package/

Comment: The files are named `__init__.py` the stack overflow interpreted the double underscore as commands... I'll read ur link, thanks!

Comment: you should **specify the full file path** if you are using `sts.path.append()`. Whilst it can be done (and i have seen it in production code), it is generally considered to be "bad practice" to fragment a project like this....